# Using WampServer to put my website online (not localhost)

Tags: wamp, wampserver, web-testing

I am using wamp as my server on my local machine to load my website on my localhost but I am trying to get my website up on the internet with my domain name. I have searched online and I haven't found an answer that solved my problem. The one that came close was using a virtual host with my domain name but I was unable to use that domain name to load my website on a different website.

Does anyone know how to load up a website and put it online using a domain name? Or is there a better/easier approach to it than using Wamp Server?

Comment: Well a better approach would be to use a hosting service where they ghave the skill to properly harden their servers against attack

Answer (score 0):

So you have your website running on your local machine. I guess it not only responds to 'http://localhost' or 'http://127.0.0.1' but also your local machine's IP address it probably obtained from your router via DHCP.

Basically you just need to perform these steps:

- tell your router to always assign the same IP for this machine
- tell your router to forward requests from outside to port 80 to your local machine, port 80.
- test whether http://<your router's official IP> will produce your website. If not check the above steps
- Since your router probably receives a dynamic IP from your provider that address can change anytime. Find a dynamic DNS site, register your account and tell your router to use that dynamic DNS service. At this moment you know about a domain name which should point to your router's IP address.
- test whether http:// produces your website

There you go, your website on your local machine is accessible from the internet.